# How to edit PostgreSQL configuration files from cPanel?

Tags: vba, postgresql, excel, cpanel

I am trying to connect to a remote PostgreSQL database via VBA. I read [here](https://admin-ahead.com/forum/cpanel/how-to-configure-remote-access-postgresql/) about the Database server configuration to make this possible but i cannot find the configuration files in cPanel file manager(I am new to cPanel).
It says in the article that i can find the **pgsql config file** here **/var/lib/pgsql/data** but i do not see a **var** folder in the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can NOT access your /var directory through cPanel file manager. cPanel file manager has limited directory access and due to that you can not access /var folder which is present outside the cPanel user home directory

You will have to access your server with root user through SSH and then try to access /var/lib/pgsql/ directory